# INACTIVE OWNER OR USER error

Tags: error-handling, salesforce, case

While creating a case an error is appearing INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER I verified the user and it is actif. Can some one help me to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it getting assigned to a queue or are there any assignment rules.

Check them, also look at debug logs while performing save operation, might help.